# Extremely low contrast in 2022 Developer Survey results

Tags: bug, design, survey

The "All countries" tab in the "Geography" section of the 2022 Developer Survey has extremely low contrast. This affects readability. On low brightness, it is hard to see that there is any text in the white/grey rows. On higher brightness, it is difficult to read.

Example below:

[image]

[Link to section in question](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=announcement-banner&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2022&utm_content=results#key-territories-all-countries)